# Unable to Read/Write files from Android phone, except AVD in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Here is my Java code to Read/Write in `Android-Studio`. The below snippet works with `AVD Emulator` in `Andorid Studio` but failed to work in Real Android Phone

```
 public static ArrayList<String> dosyaOku1(Context context){
            ArrayList<String> itemList = null;
            try {
                FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(DosyaAdi1);
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
                itemList = (ArrayList<String>) ois.readObject();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                itemList = new ArrayList<>();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Only the Read/Write can not be implemented for **Real** `Android Phone` in `Android-Studio`

Answer (score 0):

If your phone system above lollipop,even if you add the permissions line in manifest.xml, you need to give your app permission write an read storage access by going to your app info in your phone.

go to your setting > apps > choose your app > permission.
And turn On the storage "permission".

- first make sure that you gave write and read storage permission in your manifest.xml
  [image: Example: How to turn on storage permission to your app]

Comment: Thank you. But which permission should I get. This is for phone memory not external. I can't found it. There are external permission. like following. <uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE” />

Comment: Android external storage can store files in SD card or device build-in flash disk memory. Internal and external is only a logical classification.
that's mean the external storage is you phone storage also.
just keep using these permissions:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: Even if you gave these permissions in android 5.0 or 6.0 and above,after installing your app you must go to the app info permissions and turn on storage, or you can add a popup confirm dialog to write storage when you open your app.
for more information about internal and external storage and how to add popup confirm dialog visit this link:
https://www.dev2qa.com/android-read-write-external-storage-file-example/